# How to seperate validation error list in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, controller

Code in blade

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<ul>
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
@endif

Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
```

Validation Code

```
 $data = $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
    ]);
```

I wanna display each error under its input field.

Comment: You can add validation for client side also. Don't give access to controller until the validation get succeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add error message after input field

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control" required="required" name="name" type="text" id="name">
        {{ $errors->first('name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could pass in a 2nd parameter to format the message, that's pretty neat thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To display each error seperatly you can just use `$errors->first()` and pass in the field name you're requesting. See the following example.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

Name: <input type="text" name="name">
{{ $errors->first('name') }}
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
{{ $errors->first('phone') }}
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
{{ $errors->first('email') }}
```

Notice after each field I call `$errors->first()`

Answer (score -1):

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</small>
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
<small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</small>
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
{{ $errors->first('email') }}
```

If condition is not needed if u don't want to show all errors at a place.

Also, two types the error message can be display

```
{{ $errors->first('name') }}
<small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</small>
```